# How to create a list of keys in a nested dictionary based on two conditions?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, nested, list-comprehension

Let's say we have a dictionary:

```
 m_dict = {'2011-04-01': {'asprin': (232, -7, -4, 1), 'glucose': (3, 4, -3)},
           '2011-04-02': {'clb': (-7, -2, 8), 'humulin': (3, -6, -3), 'crack': (7,-5)},
           '2011-04-03': {'otc': (-1, 34, -45), 'tussin': (-2, 8)} }
```

I'm trying to sort this dictionary in decending order based on the number of drugs a date holds, but if two dates have the same number of drugs then sort those dates in ascending order.
So, the list in this case should be:  `['2011-04-02', '2011-04-01', '2011-04-03']`.

I understand how to sort based on the number of drugs, but confused on how to implement another sorting condition if the number of drugs are the same.

Something like this? I'm trying to do it in a single statement using combinations of comprehension. But this doesn't apply the rule: if the number of drugs is the same for two dates, then sort those two dates in date_lst in ascending order.

```
date_lst = [key for key in sorted(m_dict.keys(), key = lambda item[key]): len(item[key]))
```

Comment: @dspencer: That was true for a long time, but Python 3.7 [dictionaries officially keep stable order](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort the list by a tuple of values, the length of the dictionary element (negated to sort descending) and then the key:

```
date_lst = [key for key in sorted(m_dict.keys(), key=lambda k: (-len(m_dict[k]), k))]
```

Output:

```
['2011-04-02', '2011-04-01', '2011-04-03']
```

Note that you can just use `m_dict` rather than `m_dict.keys()` since [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) operates on the keys when sorting a `dict`, not the values (since that's what `dict` returns as an iterator). So you can simplify to:

```
date_lst = [key for key in sorted(m_dict, key=lambda k: (-len(m_dict[k]), k))]
```

Comment: Don't really need `.keys()` here.

Comment: Yes! I understand, thank you. The length is checked first and if lengths of two key values are equal then sorting by those specified keys will be checked.

Comment: @M.Cow exactly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
sorted_key_list = sorted(m_dict.keys(), key = lambda t:len(m_dict[t].items()))
```

If you want to make dictionary with order, use `collections.OrderDict` as follows.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
sorted_dic = OrderedDict()
for key in sorted_key_list:
    sorted_dic[key] = m_dict[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

answered already, just throwing in the [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) operator option :

```
from operator import itemgetter

sorted([(key,len(value))[0] 
        for key,value in m_dict.items()]
       ,key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)


['2011-04-01', '2011-04-02', '2011-04-03']
```